# How to generate a number sequence / rank in R based on another column in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have a dataframe similar to as follows:

```
ID       TEXT  ReferenceTEXT  TextID  
 1        Yo        NA         NA
 2       Cool       Yup        5
 3       Nice       NA         NA
 4       Phat       Yup        5       
 5       Yup        Phat       4       
 6       Boss       NA         NA       
 7       Yay        Phat       4
```

By using `match` as in 
`dataframe$TextID  <- match(dataframe$ReferenceText,dataframe$Text, incomparables=NA)`

I was able to extract the `TextID` for the `ReferenceText`. Now I'd like to get the sequence / rank of the `TextID`under a new column called `SequenceID` like so:

```
 ID       TEXT  ReferenceText  TextID  SequenceID
 1        Yo        NA         NA         NA
 2       Cool       Yup        5          5-1
 3       Nice       NA         NA         NA
 4       Phat       Yup        5          5-2
 5       Yup        Phat       4          4-1
 6       Boss       NA         NA         NA
 7       Yay        Phat       4          4-2
```

But how would I do this? What is the most practical way of accomplishing this task ? This solution is needed for a data frame of over 160,000+ observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`:

```
df$SequenceID <- paste(df$TextID, ave(df$TextID, df$TextID, FUN=seq_along), sep="-")
is.na(df$SequenceID) <- is.na(df$TextID)
df
#   ID TEXT ReferenceTEXT TextID SequenceID
# 1  1   Yo          <NA>     NA       <NA>
# 2  2 Cool           Yup      5        5-1
# 3  3 Nice          <NA>     NA       <NA>
# 4  4 Phat           Yup      5        5-2
# 5  5  Yup          Phat      4        4-1
# 6  6 Boss          <NA>     NA       <NA>
# 7  7  Yay          Phat      4        4-2
```

With `ave`, the sequence of similar ids are created and pasted together with the id. Then the correct `NA` values are defined.

**Update**

For a cleaner look, you can use `transform` to create the new column and assign it in one line and remove NA strings as you see fit:

```
newdf <- transform(df, SequenceID = paste(TextID, ave(TextID, TextID, FUN=seq_along), sep="-"))
is.na(newdf$SequenceID) <- is.na(df$TextID)
```

Comment: I think using `transform` or `with` would would be cleaner, no?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I agree. We could eliminate the dfs throughout.

Comment: This would be probably cleaner too `setDT(df)[!is.na(TextID), SequenceID := paste(TextID, 1:.N, sep = "-"), by = TextID]` which will save you the `NA` assignment too.

Comment: `transform(df, SequenceID = paste(TextID, ave(TextID, TextID, FUN=seq_along), sep="-"))` only listed inside the console, not the enviroment.  I used `df$SequenceID <- transform(df, SequenceID = paste(TextID, ave(TextID, TextID, FUN=seq_along), sep="-"))` the enviroment dataframe returned `SequenceID.SequenceID` `NA-NA` `5-1` etc. I like your first answer better and will try @DavidArenburg's but your's seems easier to interpret.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Your function returned `Error: could not find function "setDT"`

Comment: You can eliminate the NA values as you would with the first example. For David's answer you need the `data.table` package. `library(data.table)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe %>% 
  group_by(ReferenceTEXT) %>% 
  mutate(SequenceID = ifelse(is.na(TextID), NA_character_, paste(TextID, seq_len(n()), sep="-")))
# Source: local data frame [7 x 5]
# Groups: ReferenceTEXT [3]
# 
# ID   TEXT ReferenceTEXT TextID     SequenceID
# (int) (fctr)        (fctr)  (int) (chr)
# 1     1     Yo            NA     NA    NA
# 2     2   Cool           Yup      5   5-1
# 3     3   Nice            NA     NA    NA
# 4     4   Phat           Yup      5   5-2
# 5     5    Yup          Phat      4   4-1
# 6     6   Boss            NA     NA    NA
# 7     7    Yay          Phat      4   4-2
```